# CSS overflow hidden doesn't work with videos

Tags: css

I have 3 divs. The first is called "container" and the other one is called "video1". "Video1" contains the `video`. Here is the code.

```css
.video1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4rem;
  left: 15rem;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video1 video {
  width: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

    <div class="video1">

        <video src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

    </div>
</div>
```

But when I resize the screen the video doesn't get hidden. displays outside of the div.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried applying `overflow:hidden` to the container instead? And btw, you should post both your HTML and CSS to help us debug :o)

Comment: "I have 3 divs. " I only see one here; feels like missing from the example to fully reproduce this here.

Comment: Maybe need to add a width to the video1 div?

Comment: I added with but it still doesn't work.